# Are split antlers as good as whole antlers for chewing?

Tags: dogs, chewing

We are expecting a puppy in June and I'm anticipating that chewing stage. We already bought 3 sizes of Kongs for the pup to grow through, but my understanding is that those are for treats, especially good for crate training.

I've noticed antlers in both our mainstream Petco as well as our local boutique pet stores. They are all "split" antlers. It wasn't until I researched antler questions here that I realized that antlers were even sold whole. We're expecting a rough-coated (Lassie style, not border) collie and I don't know their chew strength yet.

Can anyone fill me in on the chew resistance of split versus whole antlers and whether they have any side effects (digestive/dangerous splitting/teeth cleaning ability/etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be any significant difference between them except the dog having a far easier time to chew on the split ones, especially if inexperienced (which makes them the better option for now). The puppy might lose interest on the full antler without being able to get to the "sweet filling".

Typically there shouldn't be any splitting etc. (that's what makes antlers so great compared to bones). But as usual, keep an eye on your dog, especially the first few times.

As for digestion: keep it a rare snack and it should be fine without any side effects (the added nutrients will be a plus then). The dog will most likely chew on it for a while rather than trying to eat it immediately anyway.

Comment: I didn't know that the interior was yummy.  I assume by rare you mean once or twice a week?

Comment: @SnappingShrimp it's a snack. Most likely it will last a week or even longer. It's just no replacement for regular food.